# How JDK RSACore.priCrypt works and what does getBlindingRandomPair mean?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I am working on how JDK realizes RSA decryption. I located the function "priCrypt" in RSACore.class, and below is the code:

```
    private static byte[] priCrypt(byte[] var0, BigInteger var1, BigInteger var2) throws BadPaddingException {
        BigInteger var3 = parseMsg(var0, var1);
        RSACore.BlindingRandomPair var4 = null;
        var4 = getBlindingRandomPair((BigInteger)null, var2, var1);
        var3 = var3.multiply(var4.u).mod(var1);
        BigInteger var5 = var3.modPow(var2, var1);
        var5 = var5.multiply(var4.v).mod(var1);
        return toByteArray(var5, getByteLength(var1));
    }
```

`var0` is the cipher_text, `var1` is the modulus, and `var2` is the private_key. 
My Question is what does "getBlindingRandomPair" mean? I can not figure out its function. If going deeper, can anyone explain how is the BigInteger.modPow function realized?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is the non-CRT version of the RSA privatekey primitive, which is used for decryption and signing (and no, signing is NOT encrypting with the private key, although *part* of it is mathematically similar; there are dozens of Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX about that). The non-CRT version is unnecessarily costly and should be avoided by using the CRT-form key (`RSAPrivateCrtKey`) in which case `RSACore` uses `crtCrypt()` instead.

Also I hope you know that the RSA encryption/decryption and signing/verifying are NOT merely the primitives x^e mod pq and y^d mod pq, which by themselves are not secure; a 'padding' operation *must always* be added, and for signature usually a secure hash (aka digest) operation must also be added; these are also extensively discussed on crypto and security.

Second, this code is apparently decompiled, since in addition to losing the identifiers it elides a constant `if` test and combines what are a separate declaration and assignment in the source. I recommend using the source instead, as it partially answers some of your questions. (Plus at least under the old Sun licensing, decompiling was a violation of the license terms, although people did it anyway. I haven't relooked under the new split OpenJDK vs commercial licensing.) All OpenJDK source is available under https://hg.openjdk.java.net and I've seen references to (but am not familiar with) several other repositories.

> what does "getBlindingRandomPair" mean?

RSA [privatekey] blinding is a technique to prevent (or at least reduce) timing attacks that can allow an adversary to find out your private key, thus destroying your security by breaking the fundamental requirement of public-key cryptography that the private key be kept private and not known by an adversary. (Note there are other kinds of blinding used in crypto, some including RSA, so don't get them mixed up.) It uses a randomized pair of related exponent values (called u and v) applied before and after the 'real' privatekey operation, and `getRandomBlindingPair` means to get the pair of random blinding values. Wikipedia has a good [brief description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Timing_attacks) and the source (see above) has details of exactly how it is implemented. Note that in some error cases it isn't as random as intended; this is a tradeoff between best possible security, and having people's programs sometimes fail for reasons that most users would never comprehend or be able to fix quickly and maybe not at all, which would make them pretty unhappy with Java.

> can anyone explain how is the BigInteger.modPow function realized?

Not in a Stack answer. Efficient (fast) algorithms and methods for computing with 'bignums', and particularly modular bignums (as RSA uses), have been much studied by mathematicians in recent decades, due in large part to their use in public-key cryptography like RSA. The implementation of `modPow` uses these methods; as of java 8 it uses methods due to Karatsuba, Toom-Cook, and Montgomery, and I wouldn't be surprised if later versions (which I haven't bothered downloading yet) add more. Unless you want to learn (or already know) a good bit of higher mathematics, you are best off trusting `modPow` meets the (simple) specification implied by its name and stated in the Javadoc, and ignoring the internals.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and professional answer.  I am not quite familiar with JDK source code, I just write an RSA encryption example in IDEA and debug into RSACore. Now I found the source on github [JDK](https://github.com/zxiaofan/JDK). Thanks a lot!